# C# How to resume paused jobs from a printer redirecting to another printer? Is it possible?

Tags: c#, printing

I am trying to resume my printjobs from an offline printer to be printed in another printer. I feel that I am almost there but I am not sure if the `AddJob()` is the best approach, or I am just not adapting it right to the code I have.

So what I have at the moment is the following. I gather the jobs from the old printer and I also know how to cancel them. But I can't seem to find a way to retrieve the information from the old queue and transfer to the new printer and resume.

```
// Create the printer server and print queue objects
        LocalPrintServer localPrintServer = new LocalPrintServer();
        PrintQueue defaultPrintQueue = LocalPrintServer.GetDefaultPrintQueue();

        //Set the correct printer
        pname = this.listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        //Gather print jobs from the offline printer
        GetPrintJobsCollection(defaultprinter);

        //Note sure how to use this
        foreach (string file in printJobCollection)
        {              
            // Call AddJob
            PrintSystemJobInfo myPrintJob = defaultPrintQueue.AddJob(file);

            // Write a Byte buffer to the JobStream and close the stream
            Stream myStream = myPrintJob.JobStream;
            Byte[] myByteBuffer = UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetBytes("This is a test string for the print job stream.");
            myStream.Write(myByteBuffer, 0, myByteBuffer.Length);
            myStream.Close();
        }

        //Cancel old jobs on the old printer
        CancelPrintJob(defaultprinter);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
prntJob.InvokeMethod("Resume", null);
```